# Warning when reassigning to series in pandas

Tags: pandas, series

Please suggest the right way of doing the following.

```
data_tr['loss'] = data_tr['loss'].apply(lambda x:x**0.25)
```

```
<ipython-input-368-59c3c700212e>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

```
data_tr['loss'] = data_tr['loss'].apply(lambda x:x**0.25)
```

Comment: `data_tr=data_tr.copy()` before that line. Also, replace that line with `data_tr['loss'] *= .25` would be much faster (you still need the copy though).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what's suggested?

```
data_tr.loc[:,'loss'] = data_tr.loc[:,'loss']**0.25
```